# Customize ctrl+click over whole line vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to be able to link a line of words together after the first word, so that when I ctl+hover over it in vscode I can click on the whole thing. Like below when you ctrl+hover over "the", the rest gets underlined and you can click on it as a whole.

Given ***the* user "userName" uploads a file "fileName"**

[image]

Is there a way to do this as part of an extension in vscode?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Actually, I need to use the similar combination of ctrl+hover for something else(trigger the intellisense popup), but haven't find anything useful anywhere else yet.